# Como faço para quando eu clicar em um botão aparecer outro abaixo

Tags: html

Olá eu gostaria de quando eu clicar em um botão abrir outro link e na mesma pagina aparecer outro botão sem apagar o 1°

Comment: Você precisa especificar melhor o que deseja fazer, com quais linguagens? Você pretende fazer isso somente com HTML? Vai precisar de Javascript para isso. Neste caso, você está usando jQuery ou quer fazer com Javascript puro? Esse botão escondido vai ser carregado já de início página (antes de aparecer ao clicar no outro botão) ou vai ser carregado dinamicamente? Sua pergunta está muito vaga.

Answer (score 3):

Cara você tem que usar JavaScript.

Segue em exemplo funcional com jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready (function() {
  
  $("#button1").click( function() {
    
    $("#button2").fadeIn("slow");
    
    });
 
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button1">Botão 1</button>

<button hidden id="button2">Botão 2</button>
```

Comment: html no meu blogger

Comment: ? como assim? no Blogger deve ter JavaScript, basta arrumar um jeito de criar umas linhas de código

Comment: sim javascript,eu quero quando eu clicasse no meu botão criasse outro abaixo e abrisse um link em outra aba

Comment: boa tarde, tem como mostrar um botao ao submter um form, em vez de ser ao clicar um botao?

Comment: Cara, você precisa capturar o evento "submit" do formulário e executar a função que você quer mostrar o botão